# Bumblebee HDMI not detected

Tags: dell, hdmi, bumblebee, inspiron

I try to use my TV connecting on my PC using HDMI cable.
I installed bumblebee.

I launch "lspci -v", and this is the ouput for my card :

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 525M] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
!!! Unknown header type 7f

01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 High Definition Audio Controller (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
!!! Unknown header type 7f
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

When I run "xrandr", I've got :

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
1366x768       60.0*+
1360x768       59.8     60.0  
1024x768       60.0  
800x600        60.3     56.2  
640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

So it's seems that my nvidia card with HDMI port it's not detected.

And when I connect my TV, nothing happened.

When I try to launch "bumblebeed", this is the ouput :

```
[ERROR]Invalid configuration: no driver configured.
```

Someone can help me resolve this problem please ? 
Thank you

Comment: The same issue I also have with HDMI. Although I have installed nvidia-prime with Driver Version: 331.38 the external monitor is not seen.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall bumblebee first and install the following:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-319 nvidia-settings-319 nvidia-prime
```

Comment: But doesn't that prevent him from using his dedicated GPU? Assuming he has Optimus technology on his laptop

Comment: Here the output of xrandr and lspci -v : http://pastebin.com/kL5U2jJy

Only my laptop screen is detected, but in the lspci output, I've got something.